# Equation of an Ellipse problem

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

Given:
The foci $(-4,-4)$ and $(-4,10)$. A covertex $6√ 2$ units away from a focus. Write the equation of the ellipse in standard form.

How do you get the other data. I'm so confused. Do you do the distance formula for point P?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the sum of the two distances of any point on a ellipse to each focal point is [constant](http://www.mathopenref.com/ellipse.html).

Since you know the distance between a focal point and a covertex, you can derive what the sum of these distances (which is constant) should be equal to. From this you can find an expression for the major and minor axis, after which writing the standard form should be easy.

Comment: so should the length of the lines be equal together?

Comment: from the f1 and f2 to point covertex

Comment: @Codex Did you look at the link in my answer, because it has a nice illustration of it.

Comment: Here is a nice diagram as well http://www.mathwarehouse.com/ellipse/images/picture-of-ellipse.gif